# Como faço para limpar uma lista em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Esse é minha lista em  HTML;

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><fmt:message key="label.sagresPessoal.tela.prestacao.unidade.jurisdicionada" /></label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
         <select id="idUJ" name="prestacaoFolha.idUnidadeGestora" class="form-control select2 ">
             <option value ="">-</option>
             <c:forEach items="${listPessoaJuridica}" var="PJ">
                 <option value="${fn:replace(PJ.codigo,'.','')}">${PJ.nome}</option>
             </c:forEach>
         </select>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Eu conseguir esvaziar os outros campos asssim;

```
$('#idPeriodoInicio').val("");
    $('#idMotivo').val("");
    $('#idPeriodoFim').val("");
```

Porém não tive o mesmo sucesso com a lista, eu tentei dessa forma;

```
$('#idUJ option').each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {
        $('#idUJ').val().splice(0,$('#idUJ').val().length);
    }
});
```

Como devo fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isso:

```js
$('#idUJ')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value="">-</option>');
```

## EDIT

Ou uma forma mais limpa, sugerida pelo @Sam nos comentários:

```js
$('#idUJ').html('<option value="">-</option>');
```

Comment: Pq usar 4 métodos se pode usar apenas 1: `$('#idUJ').html('<option value="">-</option>');`? :)

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o Jquery, você pode fazer desta forma:

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZaXnYkHGqIhqTbJ6MB4l9Frs/r7U4jlx7ir8PJYBqbI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<select id="droplist">
 <option>Opção 1</option>
 <option>Opção 2</option>
 <option>Opção 3</option>
 <option>Opção 4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Apagar Opções" onclick="Apagar()">

<script type="text/javascript">
 function Apagar(){
  $("#droplist").empty();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Bom e compacto. Mas pelo exemplo na questão ele quer que mantenha o primeiro item. Seria algo como `$("#idUJ").empty().append('<option value="">-</option>');` (Mundo pequeno hein, Bins? :P)

Comment: Realmente o mundo está muito pequeno :-) Considerando o que você falou, seria desta forma que você comentou.